# When can I equate coefficients?

Tags: polynomials

I have the following simple problem:

Consider the polynom P(x) = x³ + ax² + bx + c of real coefficients. Knowing that...

- -1 and (1 + $\alpha$) are roots of P(x) = 0
- $\alpha > 0$
- the rest of the division of p(x) by (x-1) is 8

**find the value of $\alpha$.**

---

Now, I understand (1 - $\alpha$) is a root too and I can solve it by writing: (x+1)(x - 1 - $\alpha$)(x - 1 + $\alpha$) = 0

Since P(1) = 8,

$ (1+1)(1 - 1 - \alpha)(1 - 1 + \alpha) = 8 \Leftrightarrow 2(\alpha)(\alpha) = 8$

$\alpha$ = 2

My real doubt reside on **why the following method does not work**:

- Since -1 is root, a - b + c - 1 = 0
- Since (1 + $\alpha$) is root, a(1 + $\alpha$)² + b(1 + $\alpha$) + c + (1 + $\alpha$)³ = 0
- From both equations, a - b + c - 1 = a(1 + $\alpha$)² + b(1 + $\alpha$) + c + (1 + $\alpha$)³

Comparing the coefficients, (1 + $\alpha$) = -1 and $\alpha$ = 2i follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method of equating coefficient with a polynomial is based on the fact that the equation works for all values of x.

Now the "comparing coefficient" you did on

"From both equations, $a - b + c - 1 = a(1 + α)² + b(1 + α) + c + (1 + α)³$"

doesn't work because $a, b, c$ are fixed (becuase of the given constraints), you can not plug in different values to it like you would do with a polynomial in $x$

Comment: Oh, I see. I was comparing the values of X and not the coefficients. Dumb me. Thanks, mate.